# How insert data from foreign key of another table?

Tags: php, yii2

I've got a txt file with many rows. I insert data from every row into db.

```
foreach (... => ...) {
 ...
 $types = new QueryTypes();
 $types->query_type = $prepared_data_from_file;
 $types->save();
 $logs = new Logs();
 $logs->query_type = ...
 ...
}

-----------------------------------------------------
|                     LOGS                          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|  log_id (PK) | query_type (FK from query_type_id) |
-----------------------------------------------------


---------------------------------
|             QUERYTYPES        |
---------------------------------
|query_type_id (PK)| query_type |
---------------------------------
```

I need something like

```
INSERT INTO LOGS(query_type) VALUES (SELECT query_type_id FROM QUERYTYPES)
```

How could I insert column query_type_id from QUERYTYPES into column query_type in LOGS in yii2?

Comment: `$logs->query_type = $type->query_type_id`

Comment: I tried this way, but it works only once for the first coincidence.

Comment: If your loop is correct then it will work everytime.

Comment: Other data inserts correct for every row, don't know what's wrong

Comment: show controller code

Comment: I think the problem is that query_type in QUERYTYPES is UNIQUE (I don't need reiterations). After the vaule was saved for the first time in QUERYTYPES loop leaves <null> for the next.

Comment: In controller I only call this function with loop and nothing else. $log = new Logs; $log->logUpload(); return $this->render('index');

Comment: Seems unclear to me. What you want to accomplish? Complete code to save data is needed here to understand better.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I solved this problem

Comment: Does your `query_type_id` has autoincrement?

Answer (score 1):

You use a `SELECT` query instead of `VALUES`

```
INSERT INTO LOGS (query_type)
SELECT query_type_id
FROM QUERYTYPES
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ? :

`INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES(NULL, (SELECT query_type_id FROM QUERYTYPES WHERE query_type = 'your_query_type_here'))`

Comment: I don't need sql query, I ask about correct inserting values from FK in yii2.

Comment: my bad, didn't see the tag.. You should write it in your post, though